# Flutter OnChanged behaviour in Radios with multiple groups not working as expected

Tags: flutter, radio-button, radiobuttonlist

Hi The problem is I have multiple groups of RadioButtons hence can't figure out how onChanged method will work for each group.
 I have a list of students and want to make a widget where a teacher can mark attendance of students by clicking on one of the Radio Buttons( present,absent,holiday,half day etc.)
Here is the implementation

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
print('number students ${studentList.students.length.toString}');
return ListView.builder(
    itemCount: studentList.students.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      var gp = studentList.students[index].id;
      return Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Card(
          elevation: 10,
          child: ListTile(
            title: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
              child: Text(
                studentList.students[index].name,
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
            ),
            leading: CircleAvatar(
                radius: 30,
                backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                    studentList.students[index].details['photo'])),
            trailing: Column(
              children: <Widget>[],
            ),
            subtitle: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text('Phone: ' +
                    studentList.students[index].details['phone']),
                Text('Batches:'),
                Container(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  height: 50,
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: studentList.students[index].batches.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, batchIndex) {
                      return Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text(studentList
                              .students[index].batches[batchIndex].name),
                        ],
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Radio(
                            groupValue: gp,
                            value: 0,
                            onChanged: (int e) {
                              print(e);
                              print(gp);
                              updateSelectedAttendance(gp, e);

                            },
                          ),
                          Text('P')
                        ],
                      ),
                      Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Radio(
                            groupValue: gp,
                            onChanged: (int e) {
                              print(e);
                              print(gp);
                              updateSelectedAttendance(gp, e);

                            },
                            value: 1,
                          ),
                          Text('Ab')
                        ],
                      ),
                      Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Radio(
                            groupValue: gp,
                            onChanged: (int e) {
                              print(e);
                              print(gp);
                              updateSelectedAttendance(gp, e);

                            },
                            value: 2,
                          ),
                          Text('Hd')
                        ],
                      ),
                      Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Radio(
                            groupValue: gp,
                            onChanged: (int e) {
                              print(e);
                              print(gp);
                              updateSelectedAttendance(gp, e);

                            },
                            value: 3,
                          ),
                          Text('H')
                        ],
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    });
```

}

```
 updateSelectedAttendance(int gp, int e) {
setState(() {
  gp = e;
  print('gp ${gp.toString()} -- e ${e.toString()}');
});
```

}

[image]

Here because there would be multiple students , hence there would be multiple groups of Radio Buttons so I have assigned each group a groupValue of id of the individual student. And because there are 4 radio buttons for each student (present,absent,holiday,halfday), I have assigned values of 0,1,2,3. And in onChanged method I am equating gp=value;
But it is not behaving the way I want it to behave.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
//For the deom purpose I'm using Map List...
  //Replace the above with your custom model
  List<Map> studentList=[];
  //Create attendance list to hold attendance
  Map<String,String> attendance={};

  List<String> labels=['P','Ab','Hd','H'];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getData();
  }

  getData(){
    //Use your own implementation to get students data
    //For deom I'm using offline data
    studentList.add({
      'id':'ID1',
      'name':'Naveen Avidi',
      'details':'A Programmer'
        //other fields...
    });
    attendance['ID1']='P';
    //or null if emtpy
    studentList.add({
      'id':'ID2',
      'name':'Ram',
      'details':'An Engineer'
        //other fields...
    });
    attendance['ID2']='Ab';
    //or null if emtpy
    studentList.add({
      'id':'ID3',
      'name':'Satish',
      'details':'A Developer'
        //other fields...
    });
    attendance['ID3']='Hd';
    //or null if emtpy
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar:AppBar(
      title:Text('Title')),
      body: Container(
        color:Colors.white,
          child: ListView.builder(
    itemCount: studentList.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Card(
          color:Colors.cyan,
          elevation: 10,
          child: ListTile(
            title: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
              child: Text(
                studentList[index]['name'],
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,color:Colors.black),
              ),
            ),
            leading: CircleAvatar(
                radius: 30,
              //no pic available 
            ),
            trailing: Column(
              children: <Widget>[],
            ),
            subtitle: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text('Phone: ' +
                    studentList[index]['details'],
                    style:TextStyle(color:Colors.black)),
                Text('Batches:',style:TextStyle(color:Colors.black)),
//                 Container(
//                   width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
//                   height: 50,
//                   child: ListView.builder(
//                     itemCount: studentList.students[index].batches.length,
//                     itemBuilder: (context, batchIndex) {
//                       return Column(
//                         crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
//                         children: <Widget>[
//                           Text(studentList
//                               .students[index].batches[batchIndex].name),
//                         ],
//                       );
//                     },
//                   ),
//                 ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                    children: labels.map((s){
                      return Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Radio(
                            groupValue: attendance[studentList[index]['id']],
                            value: s,
                            onChanged: (newValue) {
                              setState((){
                                attendance[studentList[index]['id']]=newValue;
                              });
                            },
                          ),
                          Text(s,style:TextStyle(color:Colors.black))
                        ],
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    })
      ),
    );
  }
```

[image: SS]