# How to set default value for radio group in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am creating a group of radiobuttons in flutter using json, but I want to default to an element of the group. How I do this?

For example:

Values: 1,2,3,4.

JSON default = 3.

So Radius 3 = checked.

I am using the following example: [see here the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60053914/flutter-onchanged-behaviour-in-radios-with-multiple-groups-not-working-as-expect?answertab=oldest#tab-top)

Comment: *If groupValue and value match, this radio will be selected.* From the docs: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Radio-class.html

Comment: I made a radio group package. With this package, you just set `indexOfDefault` to your chosen index, and it does it for you. https://pub.dev/packages/radio_group_v2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to get the default value from the json.

```
value_from_json = 1 ;
```

Let's assumed this is a part of your Radio buttons widget. the `_radioValue` variable is the one responsible for the selected value.
So you have to initialize the value early on .

```
int _radioValue = value_from_json ;
```

The selected value will be the one with the radio that have the same `value` field

```
children: <Widget>[
Radio(
   value: 0,
   groupValue: _radioValue,
   onChanged: (int value) {
       setState(() {
         _radioValue = value;
       });
   },
),
Radio(
       value: 1,
       groupValue: _radioValue,
       onChanged: (int value) {
           setState(() {
             _radioValue = value;
           });
       },
    )
]
```